# Pandas - Combine/Concatenate two values from same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe with the column 'Department' with 6 different variables.

However, when I have created a new df, using:

`indicator = dept.groupby('Department')[['Assignment Status']].count()`

The df contains two entries for 'R&D Operations':

```
Department          Assignment Status

Business Services   17616
Operations          112958
Quality Assurance   28070
Quality Control     32860
R&D Operations      63206
R&D Operations      275
```

This must be some type of format difference from my original df.  How can I combine these two entries from the 'Department' Column.

Many thanks

Comment: Try replacing both values for a common one and then do the groupby. It seems that you could have an extra space in one of them, so perhaps a simple strip could be enough

Comment: I would suggest you to **strip off** any white space from the department column first. `dept['Department'] = dept.Department.str.strip()`. And then do what you want to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue must be because of white-spaces in the values as @CypherX and @Dani suggested

```
# To remove the white spaces from both ends (left and right)

dept.Department = dept.Department.str.strip() 

# Then perform the groupby operation

indicator = dept.groupby('Department')[['Assignment Status']].count()
```